# Python -- Stacklevel and logging.Adapter

Tags: python-3.x, logging

stacklevel does not seem to work with logging.Adapter

Code:

```
class LoggingAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        loggingTag = kwargs.pop('loggingTag', self.extra['loggingTag'])
        return '[%s] %s' % (loggingTag, msg), kwargs
loggerAdapter = LoggingAdapter(logger, {'loggingTag': f'sometag'})
traceback.print_stack()

logger.debug("Hello - Debug", stacklevel=3)
logger.info("Hello - Info", stacklevel=3)
logger.exception("Hello - Exception", stacklevel=4)

loggerAdapter.debug("Hello - Debug", stacklevel=3, loggingTag='NewTag')
loggerAdapter.info("Hello - Info", stacklevel=3, loggingTag='NewTag')
loggerAdapter.exception("Hello - Exception", stacklevel=4, loggingTag='NewTag')
```

Output:

```
File "loggerframework/testLoggerUtil.py", line 27, in \<module\>
newAddition("Hello,", " good morning!")
File "loggerframework/\<...\>/common_lib/logging_lib/logger.py", line 100, in __call__
return wrapper(\*args, \*kwargs)
File "loggerframework/\<..\>/common_lib/logging_lib/logger.py", line 72, in wrapper
traceback.print_stack()

2022-11-22 11:26:17,277\[DEBUG\] - dev - testLoggerUtil.py - \<module\>() - Hello - Debug
2022-11-22 11:26:17,277\[INFO\] - dev - testLoggerUtil.py - \<module\>() - Hello - Info
2022-11-22 11:26:17,277\[ERROR\] - dev - testLoggerUtil.py - \<module\>() - Hello - Exception
NoneType: None

2022-11-22 11:26:17,277\[DEBUG\] - dev - logger.py - wrapper() - \[NewTag\] Hello - Debug
2022-11-22 11:26:17,277\[INFO\] - dev - logger.py - wrapper() - \[NewTag\] Hello - Info
2022-11-22 11:26:17,277\[ERROR\] - dev - logger.py - wrapper() - \[NewTag\] Hello - Exception
NoneType: None
```

The stacklevel works as expected with a logger
It does not work the same with a logging.Adapter class, while it picks up the other

Answer (score 0):

Which python version are you running? This problem appears to have been addressed in recent updates.

When using **Python version 3.11.4**, the stacklevel option with loggerAdapter works just fine. However, I tested this on version 3.10.7 as well and I had the same issue as u.